# Intent android error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

Tengo una consulta estoy creando un `intent` para enviar en email con un pdf adjunto pero cuando se lanza el gmail se pone todo de forma correcta excepto el campo del email destino.

Mi código es el siguiente para el `Intent`:

```
            String s = mEmailCliente;


            String[] mailto = new String[1];
            mailto[0]=s;
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(String.valueOf(pdfFile)));

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Su Factura");
            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Buenas estimad@: a continuación se le adjunta su factura número F" + no_factura);
            intent.setType("application/pdf");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mailto);


            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Compartir vía: "));
```

Alguien tiene una idea porque no toma el valor de la variable llamada `s` sin embargo si al arreglo `mailto` le especifico un correo entre comillas este si lo toma correctamente. Saludos

Comment: Que cliente estas usando? Tu código puede funcionar sin problema si mEmailCliente en verdad contiene un email , en cuanto a que no se agregue el email es un problema que en ocasiones sucede, tal vez por un error del mismo cliente.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que presentas se puede deber a varias razones.

La primeras es que mEmailCliente no tenga un email o que no tenga valor.

La segundo es que si estas usando Gmail como cliente, comunmente se puede experimentar  que no se agrega la cuenta de destinatario, probablemente sea un problema del mismo cliente al tratar de agregar archivos anexos.

Te sugiero de definir el tipo ( `intent.setType("application/pdf");` ), debes definir los EXTRAS, es por esa razón que probablemente no esta tomando el email del recipiente o destinatario.

```
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(String.valueOf(pdfFile)));

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Su Factura");
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Buenas estimad@: a continuación se le adjunta su factura número F" + no_factura);        
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { mEmailCliente });



        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        intent.setType("application/pdf"); //***

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Compartir vía: "));`
```

Comment: Si era exactamente eso no estaba pasando valor, lo comprobe al poner un Toast con el valor de esa variable y en efecto no tenia información ya lo solucione gracias.

Answer (score 1):

¿ Estás seguro de que mEmailCliente tiene valor?

Prueba esto:

```
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(String.valueOf(pdfFile)));

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Su Factura");
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Buenas estimad@: a continuación se le adjunta su factura número F" + no_factura);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { mEmailCliente });



        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Compartir vía: "));`
```

Espero que te sirva.

Un saludo!!

Comment: Lo que esta realizando el OP con mailto es lo mismo que intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { mEmailCliente }); el problema es el cliente o un error que no pernite agregar el email.